# How to specify the layerStack for a VirtualDisplay created by DisplayManager?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, surfaceflinger, android-displaymanager

According to android's official document:
[virtual displays](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/layers-displays#virtual-displays)

> Virtual displays may share the same set of layers as the main display (the layer stack) or have their own set.

It is known that DisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay() can create a virtual display. But it seems it always has the same layer stack with primary display (mirrored content). How can I set a different layer stack?

Comment: I guess the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660882/android-native-code-assigning-a-surface-to-a-specific-display